# performance difference while calling method dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Is there a big performace difference between these 2 sample method calls ?

```
SampleClass sc = new SampleLib.SampleClass();
sc.DoSomething("Hello");

dynamic dyn = someAssembly.CreateInstance("SampleLib.SampleClass")
dyn.DoSomething("Hello");
```

Lets assume that

> dynamic dyn =
>   someAssembly.CreateInstance("SampleLib.SampleClass")

is not frequent call. Once it creates the instance it will continue intensivly work only with created instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to know for sure is to profile *in your context*. To set expectation, `dynamic` is pretty smart, and caches (per pattern) the actual code-path. As such, it is much faster than raw reflection, however an interface should be slightly faster and has the advantage of static checking.

Personally, I'd code to an interface from a library dll that both the current code and SampleLib can reference, i.e.

```
IMyInterface foo = (IMyInterface)someAssembly.CreateInstance(
                         "SampleLib.SampleClass");
...
foo.DoSomething("Hello");
```

Comment: You mean that here we will not have any performance difference as foo.DoSomething("Hello"); will be called staticly ? no dinamic binding overhead ?

Comment: @NDeveloper *minimal* overhead. It still has to check the cache of signatures it has seen before. The point is: it isn't stupidly slow. It isn't *quite* as fast as static typing either.

Comment: @Marc Sorry what means to check the cache of signatures ? Where can I read more about this?

Comment: @NDeveloper what I mean is, it needs to check that `dyn` (the target) is of a type it has seen before, and that it has seen a call with those exact parameters (always a single `string` in your case, but trickier in the general case). So really: has it seen `SimpleClass` before? if so, it should be quick. If not, it needs to (still pretty quick) figure out how to call that, and cache it.

Comment: @Mark I see, thank you very much for more details. 
Do I get right that in the code from your answer no need for such behavior as the call is performed statically.

Comment: @NDeveloper correct; there is only a type-check in the cast to `IMyInterface`